# linux drops packet when trying to route it - why?

Tags: networking, routing, iptables

I track packets using LOG targets for all chains of all tables and the last chain I see my packet in is the PREROUTING chain of the mangle table:

```
mangle_PREROUTING: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:0f:01:00:00:16:3e:0f:02:00:08:00
SRC=10.2.1.2 DST=10.1.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=60912 PROTO=ICMP
TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=41230 SEQ=1
```

Per http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png, I expected that packet to appear in FORWARD chain of the mangle table, but it never gets there. The only thing between these is the routing table.

```
# ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip route list
default via 192.168.178.100 dev eth3
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.1
10.1.2.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.2.1
10.5.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.5.0.1
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.1
```

So that packet should be routable via 10.1.1.1. (That system can also ping 10.1.1.2.)

iptables (all chains ACCEPT) has only these rules (except for logging at the
end):

```
-t raw -A PREROUTING -j MARK --set-xmark 0x0/0xffffffff
-t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.1.1.0/24 -d 10.2.1.0/24 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
-t mangle -A PREROUTING -p esp -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
```

But those rules should not match: The destination is 10.1.1.2 and it is not ESP...

Any hints?

Best regards, Steffen

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is the rp_filter. You have a packet with source 10.2.1.2 that was received in the interface eth0. Your route table say the network 10.2.1.2 is reached via eth3 (default route). I suppose that you don't have a typo.

If the problem is the rp_filter, packets are dropped before FORWARD.

rp_filter means "reverse path filter", usually enabled by default. Only the packets incomming from the right interface (acordding to the routes) are allowed.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```